# Can I parse an html file for the value of a certain tag using excel, based on the value of a cell?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

Apologies if the question isn't extremely clear. Here's a more thorough version:

I have a spreadsheet with two columns: file path & article title. File path contains the path to the article (html file) whose title I'm manually copy and pasting from the html file into the other column. I need to do this several hundred times, so I'm curious to know if there's a way I can automate it. The article title is found within the first `<span>` of the second `<h2>` on each html page.

Example:

Cell A1: F:\2003\030714.html

Cell B1: The Art of Basket Weaving

Cell A2: F:\2003\030718.html

Cell B2: Cooking for Cats

Is there some sort of wizardry that could help accomplish this? If I could just do a `VLOOKUP`, this would be a piece of cake, but unfortunately, both the beginning web dev and intermediate excel user in me are puzzled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you have the list of html files, you could use nodejs & cheerio (https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse each html file using jquery like syntax and then generate a csv which you could import into excel

Comment: Load each file into IE and then you can use something like `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("h2")(2).getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText`.  Google "VBA automate IE" for examples

Comment: @TimWilliams - thanks! I'll certainly try this.

Answer (score 1):

Select the range of cells containing the file path that you want to update the article title for and then run this procedure. It will check to see if each file exists and if it does it will create a file stream object to open and read the file. It will return the article title as the text between the second set of H2 tags after the first Span tag. No allowance is made to check if the end of the first Span tag has been reached. Hope this helps.

```vb
Sub UpdateArticleTitle()

Dim rngPath As Range
Dim tsObj As Object, tsFile As Object
Dim strLine As String
Dim bytSpanCount As Byte, bytH2Count As Byte
Dim strArticleTitle As String

    ' Go throught the range of selected fileds
    For Each rngPath In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
        ' Continue if the file exists
        If Dir(rngPath.Value, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            ' Initialize the variables
            bytSpanCount = 0
            bytH2Count = 0
            strArticleTitle = ""
            ' Create a file system object
            Set tsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            ' Open the HTML file
            Set tsFile = tsObj.Opentextfile(rngPath.Value)
            Do Until tsFile.AtEndOfStream
                ' Read the file
                strLine = tsFile.ReadLine
                ' Search for the first occurrence of <span>
                If bytSpanCount = 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, LCase(strLine), "<span>") > 0 Then bytSpanCount = 1
                ' If <span> has been found, then search for <h2>
                ElseIf bytSpanCount = 1 Then
                    If InStr(1, LCase(strLine), "<h2>") > 0 Then
                        If bytH2Count = 0 Then
                            bytH2Count = 1
                        ' The second occurence of <h2> has been reached so extract the Article Title
                        Else
                            ' Get all lines until the closing </h2> tag is found
                            Do Until InStr(1, LCase(strLine), "</h2>") > 0
                                strLine = strLine & tsFile.ReadLine
                            Loop
                            ' Set the article title
                            strArticleTitle = Mid(strLine, InStr(1, LCase(strLine), "<h2>") + Len("<h2>"), InStr(1, LCase(strLine), "</h2>") - InStr(1, LCase(strLine), "<h2>") - Len("<h2>"))
                            ' Exit the loop
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
            ' Close the file
            tsFile.Close
            ' Update the article title in the sheet
            rngPath.Offset(0, 1).Value = strArticleTitle
        Else
            ' Clear the article title if the file isn't found
            rngPath.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next rngPath

    Set tsObj = Nothing
    Set tsFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate how detailed you were in your response, but unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: @lith0pedion were you getting an error or just not the expected results?